# Почему используется функция без параметров?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, друзья! Изучаю JavaScript по книге. В ней такой пример:

```
function f_sort(Str1, Str2) 
{
  var Str1_1 = Str1.toLowerCase();
  var Str2_1 = Str2.toLowerCase();
  if (Str1_1 > Str2_1) return 1;
  if (Str1_1 < Str2_1) return -1;
  return 0;
}

var Mass = [ "единица1", "Единый", "Единица2" ];
Mass.sort(f_sort);
document.write(Mass.join(", "));
```

Непонятно почему в `Mass.sort(f_sort)` используется без параметров. Как он будет знать какие значения подставлять? Разве не надо тут в цикле перебирать по два значения из массива? Или я чего не понимаю еще в JavaScript, так как новичок в этом языке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке

```
Mass.sort(f_sort)
```

не происходит вызов функции `f_sort`. Здесь имеет место передача ссылки на функцию в качестве аргумента для функции Mass.sort. А вызов этой функции, должно быть, осуществляется внутри Mass.sort, уже с передачей необходимых параметров

Comment: А как различаются в JS ссылки на функцию от самого вызова функции? Тоесть если указывается ссылка на функцию то она без параметров может быть что ли?

Comment: для вызова функции необходимо указать круглые скобки после ее имени

    // передача f_sort в качестве аргумента
    Mass.sort(f_sort)   
    
    // передача результата выполнения f_sort в качестве аргумента
    Mass.sort(f_sort())

Comment: понятно, спасибо за ответ! плюсанул твой ответ